# extract json by Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have this JSON

```
   myJson = [{"linkId":"changeDriveLink","url":"/drive/rayon.header.changedrivelink?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},
             {"linkId":"affichePopinProduit","url":"/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.affichepopinproduit/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g/$N?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},
             {"linkId":"addProductToShoppingList2","url":"/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.addproducttoshoppinglist2/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"}]
```

i want to have the URLS, i tried :

```
decoded = json.loads(myJson.read())
```

and

```
decoded = json.load(myJson.read())
```

and

```
decoded = json.load(myJson)
```

but I always have this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: what is `myJson`? Where do you declare that variable. Seems like you are assigning it a string.

Comment: if myJson is a string, you probably just want `decoded = json.loads(myJson)`.

Comment: If `myJson` is exactly as you declared, then it is already a list of dicts. Do you want to _read_ or _write_ that JSON?

Comment: @tobias_k yes i need to use the 3 data of URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
decoded = json.loads(myJson)
```

which doesn't give any errors when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need read(), just dump it (if you don't have it in string representation) and then load it.

```
import json
myJson = [{"linkId":"changeDriveLink","url":"/drive/rayon.header.changedrivelink?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},{"linkId":"affichePopinProduit","url":"/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.affichepopinproduit/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g/$N?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"},{"linkId":"addProductToShoppingList2","url":"/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.addproducttoshoppinglist2/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g?t:ac=3686962/3696434","zoneId":"forceAjax"}]
myJson = json.dumps(myJson)
json.loads(myJson)
```

The result is a list of dicts:

```
[{'linkId': 'changeDriveLink',
  'url': '/drive/rayon.header.changedrivelink?t:ac=3686962/3696434',
  'zoneId': 'forceAjax'},
 {'linkId': 'affichePopinProduit',
  'url': '/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.affichepopinproduit/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g/$N?t:ac=3686962/3696434',
  'zoneId': 'forceAjax'},
 {'linkId': 'addProductToShoppingList2',
  'url': '/drive/rayon.header.promosmenu.thumbnailproduct.addproducttoshoppinglist2/804106/Paysan$0020Breton$0020beurre$0020moul$00e9$0020demi-sel$0020250g?t:ac=3686962/3696434',
  'zoneId': 'forceAjax'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is no need to 'loads' or 'dumps'. you are have already proper list-dict data.
for 'url's just use

```
[i['url'] for i in myJson]
```

Comment: can you explain more please, i don't undrestand your loop For

Comment: take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)